# When typed on image using textarea, the text gets one character delayed

Tags: javascript, canvas, textarea

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/shabbirrangwala/h9uaQ/19/  I am trying to add only 50 characters per line and 17 rows and i want to get the output in form of image. Somehow the rows and cols are not been restricted. What am i doing wrong here?

Sample Code :

```
tCtxt.canvas.width = tCtxt.measureText(this.value).width;       
var t = this.value.split('\n'); 

tCtxt.canvas.height = t.length*15;      
tCtxt.font = "12px monospace";
tCtxt.fillStyle = "black";

var y = 12;
for(var i=0; i<t.length; i++, y+=12) {
    tCtxt.fillText(t[i], 0, y);
}  
imageElem.src = tCtxt.canvas.toDataURL();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding wrap="hard" to the textarea tag to force the insertion of new lines at break points